# ObjectDataSource can't see business objects in app_code

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, business-objects

I did the following:

1. Create a simple web site
2. add NORTHWIND db connection in the app_data folder
3. Create a business object in app_code folder
4. bal.cs class for business object in biz folder in app_code
5. creat in app_code in Data folder linq to sql drage customers table in there
6. Make a new page.aspx
7. drag in dropDownList
8. configure a data source
9. Add an ObjectDataSource to the page

None of my ObjectDataSource controls in bal.cs can be seen  can see this class. 
what to do ???????????!!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Data;

public class BAL
{

    public List<String> GetCountries()
    {
        using (var context = new NORTHWINDDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.customers
                    select c.country).Tolist();
        }
    }
    public List<customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
    {
        using (var context = new NORTHWINDDataContext())
        {

            return (from c in context.customers
                    where c.country == country
                    select c).Tolist();
        }

    }
    public customer GetCustomer(string custID)
    {
        using (var context = new NORTHWINDDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.customers
                    where c.CustomerID == custID
                    select c).singleOrDefalt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure the `ObjectDataSource` manually:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource id="someid" runat="server" TypeName="BAL" 
                      SelectMethod="GetCountries">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: thanks for replaying i did this in .aspx page and class bal appeared but in the bal class when i changed its property to compile it generate an error Error The type or namespace name 'Customer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @eng sara: Where did you define the Customer class?

Answer (score 1):

Try to view the properties of your class in the App_Code folder.

If the file "Build Action" is set to "content" then this seems to happen.
As soon as you change the class to "compile" it will start to show up in the ObjectDataSource list